# High level design for updating things on a page with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a side bar currently in `ul` and `li` elements seen in the picture below.
And I have three charts on the right side of it.
Each chart has its own REST web-service to update its data.
When I click on the side bar items I want to update those charts. (Through Ajax calls)

[image]

What is the high-level design for this? For example do I need `link_to` on my `li` elements? What to put in there? How to pass params? How to make the calls? Any gems that makes the life easier?

Some high-level and even lower level design is appreciated so I know where to begin from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more an AJAX question than a rails question.

You need to add click handlers on the `li`'s (jQuery is probably the easiest way to go) and have those send an AJAX request to your REST endpoints for the charts. Depending on your setup, I would recommend having those endpoints return the data you're looking for in JSON format and then updating the values in the charts (maybe go crazy and use d3js to draw them).

I'm guessing the REST endpoints need a `physician_id` or something in order for them to return the correct data, and you'll need to get this from somewhere. I usually just add the id as a data attribute on the element.

```
    <li class="js-physician" data-id="<%= physician.id %>">Physician X</li>
```

I'm assuming you're iterating over a @physicians collection to get the list.

Then for your js do something like

```
    $(document).on('click', '.js-physician', function(e) {
      var physician_id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
      params = { // this is your AJAX object
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/some_rest_url?physician_id=' + physician_id,
        success: function(data) {
          // update the charts with the returned data
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          // handle error
        }
      };
      $.ajax(params);
    });
```

so all you have to do then is set up your callback handlers and make sure you're sending the right data.

Comment: Great, Thanks. Got an overall idea. Yes I am using D3.js for charts and yes the services are returning JSON. 
Now hopefully my last confusion is how to pass values that user has selected somehow to the "Controller" section of the application? Or maybe i don't need that because they are getting updated through Ajax.

Comment: I also see some gems like pjax-rails or rack-ajax, etc on Google! Do those things make it more complicated for a beginner like me?

Comment: The way I did it above will send the `physician_id` to the controller, which you can access as params[:physician_id]. The params hash is available in every controller action and it includes the params sent via GET or POST methods. Without knowing really anything about your app, I'm guessing they just click the `<li>` that they're interested in. The `<li>` has the data that will be sent via AJAX (the `physician_id`). You can have an event for adding and removing the data from the li, based on whether the li is 'active' or not (active being something that you define).

Comment: Also, I would say just use javascript and skip using those gems. I'm not familiar with them, but the task you're looking to do isn't very difficult. Just make the ajax request and then parse the returned data.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I am working on it, Last question: You have used "data-id" , is it different if I use "id"  instead of "data-id" ?

Comment: 'data-id' identifies it as an HTML5 data attribute. Use the 'data-' prefix for info like this. you can use 'id' if you want, but that indicates that it has a different purpose in the markup. It's just semantics so it won't change anything, you'll just have to update the `e.target.getAttribute()`.